# how to convert a day to a second in python with array list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, currying

```
def konversi(j=0):
    def minute(m=0):
        def secon(d=0):
            return ((j*60)+m)*60+d
        return secon
    return minute

data = "05:33:05"

data_split = data.split(':')
print("data = ",data)
print("data split = ",data_split)
```

i'm confuse how to append a value 'day' into fungsion

```
hours = int(data_split[0])
minutes = int(data_split[1])
second = int(data_split[2])
print("Hours = ", hours)
print("minute = ", minutes)
print("second = ", second)

konvert = konversi(hours)(minutes)(second)
print("Result konversi = ", konvert) #19985
```

i would like to change data variable from string to list
and change the data to like this

```
data = ["21 day 20 hour 9 minute 20 sec",
         "19 day 14 hour 0 minute 13 sec",
         "1 day 1 hour 1 minute 1 sec"]
```

Comment: You have 3 bits of code, and I understand you are confused about some things, but I'm not quite sure what you want to do. 

It would be helpful if you showed an example of what you code you are trying to use, and what your expected result would be.

Comment: I mean, I want to add a day value inside the data variable. And change the type of the data variable to a list variable.
And the end result I want to convert all data into seconds.
example:
data = [ 1 day 1 haour 1 minute 1 second]
result:
93600 second

Comment: So data starts like `"05:33:05"` and you want it to change to `["0 day 5 hour 33 minute 5 sec"]]`?

In your question you show a data list with multiple entries. But in the code you provided above that you are showing data starting as just one single time string. Where are all the inputs coming from? Changing one string into one list item is easy enough, but we need to structure things so we can add items.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this as your input:

```
data = ["21 day 20 hour 9 minute 20 sec",
        "19 day 14 hour 0 minute 13 sec",
        "1 day 1 hour 1 minute 1 sec"]
```

And you want to calculate the total number of seconds for each element in that list.

```
data_seconds = []
for date_str in data:
    day, _, hour, _, minute, _, second, _ = date_str.split(" ")
    total_seconds = (int(day) * 24 * 60 * 60
                     + int(hour) * 60 * 60
                     + int(minute) * 60
                     + int(second))
    data_seconds.append(total_seconds)
```

data_seconds:

```
[1886960, 1692013, 90061]
```

Comment: Thank u so much sir, you're really awesome
your code save my life :)
I've tried several times before
but still error
you're the bestttt,
thank u soo muchhh:)
I owe you one

Answer (score 0):

it might have more sence to store time data as timedelta type. anyway, if you need just total seconds you can get it this way:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from re import search

pat = r"^(?P<days>\d+) day (?P<hours>\d+) hour (?P<minutes>\d+) minute (?P<seconds>\d+) sec$"
data_dict = lambda x: {k:int(v) for k,v in search(pat, x).groupdict().items()}

res = [timedelta(**data_dict(d)).total_seconds() for d in data]  # [1886960.0, 1692013.0, 90061.0]
```